# Why won't this Alert let my view controller deallocate?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I am trying to completely deallocate my view controller from memory. After hours of testing, I've finally narrowed it down to a `UIAlertController` staying in memory which keeps my view controller from deallocating.

```
@objc func logout_click() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Confirmation", message: "Are you sure you want to log out?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "YES", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        // 'YES' button action
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            self.popInit()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "NO", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        // 'NO' button action
        alert.dismiss(animated: true)
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
func popInit() {
    //Go back to init screen
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) 
}
```

---

As long as this alert doesn't show, I can use popInit() and my view controller deallocates just fine, but after this alert shows up, even after dismissing, the view controller will not deallocate. I am not referencing any variables outside the scope of this function, so why does this not allow me to deallocate? What do I need to do to allow my view controller to deallocate?

Comment: I wonder whether it would help to have the YES action handler declare `[weak self]` and call `self?.popInit()`. Should be simple to try it...

Comment: YES! Can you post this as an answer, so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: You also might want to not dismiss alert in the action, I believe that happens automatically and it might also keep the UIAlertController in memory

Comment: By the way, very nice detective work before asking.

Comment: Thanks! Im new to swift and have been only using xcode for about a month. I like the challenge of figuring things out on my own until im completely stumped, and this was one of them.

Comment: Well I wish everyone felt that way. This is exactly how to ask a question: find the exact code that is causing the problem and show all of it while explaining just what the issue is.

Comment: It definitely looks better than pasting all 400 lines of code of my view controller 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the YES action handler declare `[weak self]` and call `self?.popInit()`.

Also, as suggested in a comment, you can replace the NO handler with `nil`.